# How to reorder columns based on a column's values from another data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`, it looks something like this:

| alpha | romeo | beta | carlos | bumblebee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha value 1 | romeo value 1 | beta value 1 | carlos value 1 | bumblebee value 1 |
| alpha value 2 | romeo value 2 | beta value 2 | carlos value 2 | bumblebee value 2 |

I also have a data dictionary `data_dict`:

| VariableName | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alpha | some value | some value |
| carlos | some value | some value |
| romeo | some value | some value |
| beta | some value | some value |
| bumblebee | some value | some value |

How do I order the column of `df` to have the same order as the entires in `VariableName` from `data_dict`?

-output:

| alpha | carlos | romeo | beta | bumblebee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alpha value 1 | carlos value 1 | romeo value 1 | beta value 1 | bumblebee value 1 |
| alpha value 2 | carlos value 2 | romeo value 2 | beta value 2 | bumblebee value 2 |

Comment: `df[, data_dict$VariableName]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `dplyr::select`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
variablenames <- c("alpha", "carlos", "romeo", "beta", "bumblebee")
data_dict <- data.frame(VariableName = variablenames,
                        column2 = "some value",
                        column3 = "some value")

df <- data.frame(alpha = 1:3,
                 romeo = 1:3,
                 beta = 1:3,
                 carlos = 1:3,
                 bumblebee = 1:3)
select(df, data_dict$VariableName)
#>   alpha carlos romeo beta bumblebee
#> 1     1      1     1    1         1
#> 2     2      2     2    2         2
#> 3     3      3     3    3         3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>